# Doctrine - Saving associations after deleting parent entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities with One-To-Many relationship - User and Log.

```php
class User {
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Log", mappedBy="user") */
    private $logs;
}
```

```php
class Log {
    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="logs")
    * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $user;
}
```

What I want to achieve is following - Once I delete the `User` entity, instead of cascade deleting all of that `User` logs, I want to be able to save those logs and still be able to keep that `user_id`. I was thinking of creating a new database table `old_logs` with the same structure as `logs` table, where all of the data from `User` entity will be copied to before deleting the `User` entity, as I believe I can't keep the `user_id` pointing to non-existing user (with the use of foreign keys).

Is something like this possible through doctrine Entity class?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/better to do a soft delete.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Do you mean by adding deleted_at column on User? Thinking about it, it does solve my problem but it still keeps the logs table filled up with unnecessary logs. My plan is to keep those logs as a potential restore option in rare cases.

Comment: why not periodically back up the data, I do this  1 per day this week, 1 per week this month and 1 per month after that  etc.  The idea is the longer it's been the less granularity is needed.  Not sure if something like that is what you mean.

Comment: Soft delete sounds like what you need. Easy implementation [already available](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html). You would indeed be keeping then reduntant records. However, you might want to add a "hard delete" option, or automated procedure after X period, to be able to hard-delete everything (both User & Log records).

Comment: I've decided to go with a soft-delete option. I was considering using a doctrine Event, but I decided to go with the easier method. I'll be deleting them anyway if they get old.